# iterations thru objects JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, iteration, for-in-loop

Hello everybody I have a short question about iteration in objects

Here's my code 
[https://jsfiddle.net/Ar2zee/9g91ouq6/]

```js
var names = {
  first: 'Sasha',
  second: 'Andrey',
  third: 'Pasha',

  lastnames: {
    firstL: 'Oga',
    secondL: 'opa',
    thirdL: 'uka'
  },
}
for (var keys in names) {
  for (var newKeys in names.lastnames) {
    console.log(names.lastnames[newKeys]);
  }
}
```

My goal it's to log once all of the `lastNAmes` `oga, opa, uka`, right now my results is 4 times each of the last name can you please  explain why it's 4 times right now and how to make once each of them

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two loops. The outer loop iterates all of the `names` object keys, which are `first, second, third and lastnames`. As the inner loop iterates over the `names.lastnames`, each of them will get logged in each iteration of the outer loop. To do what you want, simply remove the outer loop:

```
for( var newKeys in names.lastnames){
    console.log(names.lastnames[newKeys]);
}
```

If you're using this in real world code, make sure to check for `hasOwnProperty` when using a `for in` loop:

```
for( var newKeys in names.lastnames){
    if (names.lastnames.hasOwnProperty(newKeys)) console.log(names.lastnames[newKeys]);
}
```

Sidenote:

If you just want to get all the values in names.lastnames, you could also use `Object.values()`:

```js
var names = {
  first: 'Sasha',
  second: 'Andrey',
  third: 'Pasha',

  lastnames: {
    firstL: 'Oga',
    secondL: 'opa',
    thirdL: 'uka'
  }
};

console.log(Object.values(names.lastnames));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need one `for` loop:

```js
var names = {
    first: 'Sasha',
    second: 'Andrey',
    third: 'Pasha',

    lastnames: {
        firstL: 'Oga',
        secondL: 'opa',
        thirdL: 'uka'
    },
}

for (var key in names.lastnames) {
    console.log(names.lastnames[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers or node can use `Object.values()`  which returns an array.

```js
var names = {
  first: 'Sasha',
  second: 'Andrey',
  third: 'Pasha',

  lastnames: {
    firstL: 'Oga',
    secondL: 'opa',
    thirdL: 'uka'
  }
}

console.log(Object.values(names.lastnames).join());
```